# Flexicious Filter not working correctly

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, filter, flexicious

I'm using a Flexicious Ultimate datagrid for visualising some data.
I'm using the built in Filter field for some columns.

This is working fine if I don't use any labelfunction on the provided cell data.
The Flexicious filter data is automatically build from the data in the cells of that specific row. When I use a labelfunction on the cell data the filter values are shown correct, but when I select to show a specific value, the datagrid return 0 records.

Example:
The dataprover.Price = 25
In use a currency formatter so the cell data would be €25
The filter fields of the datagrid show all the different datavalues from all the cells (distinct).
In this case it would be ALL & €25. When I select to only show the fields with price = €25 the datagrid returns 0 records.

I can't seem to find the correct settings to get this fixed. 
Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: If you can provide actual code, I can try to help you. Have been working with flexicious for a year or so.

Comment: Thanks Sam! But the answer beneath is the correct fix for this problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting useLabelFunctionForFilterCompare=true?

Comment: Super! This fixed the sorting issue problem! :)

Comment: Wooo-Hooo! I had the same problem and this fixed it!