# Cant get ExtededDataGrid in Flex to filter with ComboBox on multiple columns

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, combobox, flexicious

LATEST UPDATE: Issue answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132341/flexicious-filter-not-working-correctly). Some one else at stackoverflow had a similar issue and it was resolved. Solution provided for convenience. This is the line of code I was missing:

```
 comboHeaderColumn.useLabelFunctionForFilterCompare = true;
```

that line is followed by these:

```
 comboHeaderColumn.filterComboBoxBuildFromGrid = true;
 comboHeaderColumn.labelFunction = formatState;
```

where formatState is a local method that formats the data for the combobox.

---

UPDATE: I've now got the combobox's loading with the correct data, but when I select a value nothing happens. The combo boxes load only data that is in the column, and when you select a value in the combobox, it's supposed to filter the rows on that value. It doesn't.

Thanks for looking. I'm having trouble getting multiple filters to work in Flex in Flash Builder 4 using the ExtendedDataGrid and ComboBox's. Here is an image of part of the grid:

[image: Current Data Grid]

The User Name and City filter properly if you type text into the box's above the column header and the Request Date lets you select date ranges if you click on the Custom bar, but the Request Reason and State ComboBoxes do not list anything. I've created them using comboHeaderColumn.filterComboBoxBuildFromGrid = true; but all it does is put "[object Object]" as the only other selection under All.

I've used [this](http://www.cflex.net/showFileDetails.cfm?ObjectID=415) article but it will only allow you to use a single filter for the entire grid.

My finished grid will have about 20 columns and from 20,000 to 450,000 rows of data so the filters are really important and I'll need more than one.

The code is very straight forward and loops through all the returned data and if the column is identified as a filter column it does this:

```
comboHeaderColumn.filterComboBoxDataProvider = codeValuePairs;
comboHeaderColumn.filterComboBoxLabelField = "Value";
comboHeaderColumn.filterControl = "ComboBox";
comboHeaderColumn.filterOperation = FilterExpression.FILTER_OPERATION_TYPE_EQUALS;                  
comboHeaderColumn.headerText = ac.Header;
comboHeaderColumn.dataField = ac.Name; 
if( ac.Header == "State" || ac.Header == "Request Reason" )
{
    comboHeaderColumn.filterComboBoxBuildFromGrid = true;
}   

ProfileDataColumns.push(comboHeaderColumn);
```

This creates 2 entries in the combo box: All and [object Object]

What am I missing??? Anyway, after half a day searching I decided to reach out.

Any suggestions or direction to an article would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the ExtendedDataGrid?  Is that a component you created?  Usually [object Object] means that your custom object does not implement a toString() method; so the default value is used instead.  You can work around this by specifying a toString() method in your own custom class.  Or if you're using something like XML or JSON you can often use a labelFunction or a custom itemRenderer to display the data you need.

Comment: Thanks. ExtendedDataGrid is an included component on Flex. The code itself is ActionScript and the IDE is Flash Builder. I've now got the combobox's loading with the correct data. You are correct, but the "object" it's looking for is a function that will return the proper data. I have that now, but when I select a value nothing happens.

Comment: "ExtendedDataGrid" is not a built in component of Adobe Flex; and it is not listed in the API Documentation for Apache Flex: http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/index.html .  A Google search did not bring up any details on a component named "ExtendedDataGrid".  Do you mean the AdvancedDataGrid?  I really think to help you I'd need to know where this component comes from.

Comment: Thanks Reboog, you are correct. I am new to Flex and missed that subtle point! ExtendedDataGrid is a Flex extension by [Flexicious](http://www.flexicious.com/resources/docs29/com/flexicious/grids/ExtendedDataGrid.html). I've posted up the same question on their forum and have not heard anything over there yet...

Comment: Just stumbled across this question - you do have the right answer - useLabelFunctionForFilterCompare =true - however, we don't have a forum - not sure where you posted this question. We have a support email inbox.